# Exponential blowup in Simple Proof of a theorem of Statman by Mairson

Tags: lo.logic, lower-bounds, lambda-calculus

I'm studying "[A simple proof of a theorem of Statman](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.50.4048)" by H.G. Mairson.

At page 4, he encodes set/type theory in lambda calculus.
In particular, note che "op" trick in the definition of $eq_{k+1}$.

Mairson stress the fact that this trick is essential, because writing $subset_{k+1}$ twice would cause exponential blowup in term size.
I'm asking why! That would not just double the term size?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've got it.

$eq_{k+1}$ calls (indirectly) $eq_k$, so, if I call $subset_{k+1}$ twice, I fall in an exponential blowup because of the two recursive calls of $eq_k$: it is simple to see with a "linear recurrence relation of constant order".